# Xamarin httpclient does not run more than once

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using httpclient to get data from an Api Rest through Xamarin. My problem happens when I'm going to run `httpclient` again on a new page to get back the api information, that is, this works only once, how do I solve it?

Code:

```
  private async void ObterNoticiasXbox()
        {
            var respXbox = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var uriXbox = new HttpClient()
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.newsplay.com.br")
                };
                var urlXbox = "/post/";
                var resultXbox = await uriXbox.GetAsync(urlXbox);


                if (!resultXbox.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão", "Não foi possível obter as notícias do servidor, Tente novamente mais tarde!", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                respXbox = await resultXbox.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão com o Servidor", ex.Message, "OK");
                return;

            }

            // transformando o retorno em objeto através do json e deserealize e retornando em lista
            var NXbox = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<XboxModels>>(respXbox);

            //Adicionando os itens ao ListView na Home.xaml
            XboxList.ItemsSource = NXbox;

        }



    }
```

Comment: Threading issue with how the method is designed and most likely called. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Does it throw an error or exception?  What is the behavior when it doesn't work?  What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: @Jason 
the code falls on this part of the loop if (!resultXbox.IsSuccessStatusCode)

Comment: what status code is returned?

Comment: `HttpClient` is meant to be used for the life of the application. creating too many instance can cause congestion as you will run out of sockets. Next avoid `async void` as that is fire and forget and you will not be able to catch the exceptions is any are thrown. Instead have the method return a `Task` derived result.

Comment: Also based on the `My problem happens when I'm going to run httpclient again on a new page to get back the api information` it seems you will be calling this every time the page loads. Why not load it once, cache it locally and then load it when needed on other pages.

Comment: @Nkosi 
Thanks for the tips, lack of knowledge in c sharp, I programmed php, I'm venturing into mobile and C # have an example of how to use this task?